# WebDAV support in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, file-io, webdav

I need the following functionalities over HTTP.

1. Does WebDAV provides this functionality and are there any known gotchas?
2. I am planning to access WebDAV from an IPad/IPhone application. Are there any known limitation in accessing WebDAV in iOS?

   - READ
   - WRITE (Create directory, Create a file, Update existing file)
   - DELETE (File and Directory)
   - GET DIRECTORY LISTING

Answer (score 1):

WebDAV has all those features. I don't know if there's specific iOS limitations, but there are other WebDAV apps, so I assume you can make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few good options

- Schimera Navigator is known to work,although i've heard of at least some users having problems logging in due to the case of their user name being changed by auto complete. The developer says a fix is coming for that
- This video shows another approach - http://youtu.be/4ZYqLBEayrk?t=3m18s